# Getting Two Networks to commincate

Tags: networking, subnet

As a business(Business A) we recently purchased a second business(Business B) and moved them into the same building, with each business having there own separate domains\environments.

Im now in the process of consolidation, but this will take some time.
However in the mean time I need to get the Two networks talking.
Business A is on 192.168.10.xx \24, Gateway, 192.168.10.1
Business B is on 192.168.220.xx \24, Gateway, 192.168.220.1

Business A needs to access a Server(Web server) on Business B (192.168.220.10).
Whats the best way to do this?

Im looking for a quick solution here, keeping in mind each business has there own DHCP server, DNS, Exchange, etc...

Ideas? 
Expand subnet to \16? but what about DHCP?

Answer (score 1):

Just make the (two?) gateways one common device and let it act as a router between the two networks. This way, you don't need to change anything inside the networks.

Comment: Indeed, however this would involve changing all external records.. due to ip changes

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar setup (the two networks need two different wan access):

```
network A : 192.168.1.0/24 -  gw 192.168.1.254
network B : 192.168.2.0/24 - gw 192.168.1.254
```

We put a router with this conf :

```
Router eth1 : 192.168.1.253
Router eth2 : 192.168.2.253
default gw 192.168.1.254
```

We add some route on both network gw :

```
on Network A gw : 192.168.2.0/24 -> 192.168.1.253
on Network B gw : 192.168.1.0/24 -> 192.168.2.253
```

You could also replace both of your switchs and add some Vlan, IMO the best thing to do.